Unlocking a vault fails with "correct" password
I am a bit at a loss here. I have installed the Microsoft.PowerShell.SecretStore on one of our servers an set up vaults for different accounts. The password for unlocking the vaut is saved in an xml file, which I created using "Export-Clixml". To unlock the vault, I simply get the password from the xml file via "Import-CliXml". For my admin account that works perfectly fine.
Now I have set up a second vault on the same server for a different account and again saved the password in an XML file in the same fashion as before. But for some reason that I do not understand unlocking does not work here.
I write the following script to check whether or not unlocking the vault works.
$userName = 't1_service'
write-host "1:" $userName

# Path to a file, where the password will be stored.
$PathToFile = 'D:\Powershell\Vault\' + $userName + '.xml'
write-host "2:"$PathToFile


# Safe Password in file
$credential = Get-Credential -UserName $userName -Message 'Enter Password'
write-host "3:"$credential

# Safe password to file.
$credential.Password |  Export-Clixml -Path $PathToFile


try{
    # Read Password from file
    $password = Import-CliXml -Path $PathToFile
    write-host "4:"$password
}
catch{
    # catch errors
    "An error occurred:"
    $_
    $err=$true
    write-host "5:" $_
}

if(!$err){
    write-host "6: Unlock-SecretStore"
    Unlock-SecretStore -Password $password
}

Running the script on my server with the correct account gives me the
PS D:\Powershell> .\TEST.ps1
1: t1_service
2: D:\Powershell\Vault\t1_service.xml
3: System.Management.Automation.PSCredential
4: System.Security.SecureString
6: Unlock-SecretStore
Unlock-SecretStore : Store file integrity check failed.
The provided password may be invalid, or store files have become corrupted or have been tampered with.
In D:\Powershell\TEST.ps1:32 Zeichen:2
+     Unlock-SecretStore -Password $password
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [Unlock-SecretStore], PSInvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidOperation,Microsoft.PowerShell.SecretStore.UnlockSecretStoreCommand

whereas when I simply enter Unlock-SecretStore in the powershell console an enter the password for the vault, it unlocks just fine.
When I try to convert the password from plaintext to a securestring via
$p = ConvertTo-SecureString "SuperDuperSecretPassword" -AsPlainText -Force and the try to unlock the vault via Unlock-SecretStore -Password $p that also fails with the same error message.
Could someone please help me where I taking a wrong turn?

Get-Credential is based on the dpapi where the security lays in the fact that you can only decrypt the secret under the same user and computer account. The whole catch(22) in using vaults; what are you going to do with the key to open the vault? Put it in another vault? Anyways: The general approach of dealing with credentials is to avoid them and instead rely on other means to authenticate, such as certificates or Windows authentication

You are not supposed to [edit] the question with a solution on top. Instead, you can add an answer to the question. As of now, the question makes very little sense, as there is first a "solution" - to what, exactly? One needs to read further to see what's the original issue even.

I’m voting to close this question because the OP seems to have found a solution to the (unclear) problem

sry for the mistakes on my part. it is my first post here. added an answer as vonPryz suggested.

I replaced
# Safe Password in file
$credential = Get-Credential -UserName $userName -Message 'Enter Password'
write-host "3:"$credential

# Safe password to file.
$credential.Password |  Export-Clixml -Path $PathToFile

with
# Safe Password in file
$credential = Read-Host -AsSecureString
write-host "3:"$credential

# Safe password to file.
$credential |  Export-Clixml -Path $PathToFile

and now it works.
So for some reason the get-credentials seems to be the problem. Don't know why though.

Get-Credential creates an object with a username and a secure(string) password. Read-Host -AsSecureString just creates a secure(string) password.
